# Model deforms when animating it

Tags: modeling, animation

I'm very new to Blender and I'm learning how to rig and animate characters so I can import them to Unity. I made a humanoid model and rigged it, but when I try to move its legs the model deforms a lot.

Below are the images of the rig and the modeling deforming when I move its leg, and also the image of the model in edit mode:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I avoid this from happening? I'm still new so I don't know whether or not the problem is the model, rig, or both.

Leg being lifted up:
[image]
[image]

Updated file: Leg becoming flat:

[image]

This is my blend file:

[image]

Updated blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Don't move the leg.  *Rotate* the leg.

Comment: I tried rotating the leg upward but the bottom half of the torso gets deformed that way too

Comment: At a quick glance, it doesn't look as if you've parented the top leg bones to the root bone (Ctrl-P > Keep offset) and have you parented the body to the armature with automatic weights?

Comment: Yes they're parented with automatic weights, and thanks for letting me know the leg bones weren't parented to the root

Comment: apart from the fact that the leg bones were not parented to the first spine bone, everything seems ok, you need to make some corrections though as when you rotate the leg it also moves some vertices of the other leg

Comment: Thank you, what would I need to do to make those corrections? Also, is that also the reason why the lower torso of the model gets deformed when a leg is lifted up? I don't know if it's normal or not so I provided extra images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inner faces, remove them:

[image]

Also change the modifier stack order, put the *Subdivision Surface* modifier at the bottom:

[image]

At last select all the vertices that are not supposed to move when you rotate the upper leg and remove from the upper leg vertex group:

[image]

For the updated file, assign these 2 vertices to the *UpperLeg.L* vertex group and see if it is good:

[image]

Comment: Hello, I did all these steps and it fixed the issue with the torso deforming! But now when I raise any of the legs the upper thigh of that leg gets flattened. I tested to see if removing the leg vertices from the vertex groups would help but it just messed up the leg even more. Would this be caused by the placement of the bones?

Comment: Could you please share your new file?

Comment: Of course, I have now added the updated blend file to the question

Comment: See my edit and tell if it fixes your problem

Comment: I assigned the vertices but the leg still becomes flat, I posted an image of what I'm talking about above the two blend files in the question

Comment: I'm talking about the butt vertices, these are the ones you need to assign to the upper leg, anyway it will still look a bit flat because of the way your mesh and your armature are made, if you want it to bend differently you need to make a bit more complicated mesh and maybe add a bone between the spine and leg

Comment: Oh okay thanks for all the help